# AuthSub/OAuth, ASP.NET and Google API

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, authsub

I have an Idea for a simple webApp that would cross-link information from Evernote to Google Calendar. I was able to find a good [Evernote Quickstart project](http://macrolinz.com/macrolinz/index.php/2008/12/26/get-it-while-its-hot-evernote-web-quickstart-for-c/) but I am now searching for something to start with to begins accessing Calendar. Please advise if you know any good resources with code samples that would show me how to do the dirty work (i mean the authetication either via OAuth/AuthSub).

From what I have read about using OAuth with Google, it seems that you have to have a registered domain - I need to be able to access the service from my laptop's development server, so I guess I must stick with AuthSub.

When I 'googled' for this topic I found many questions similar to mine, yet none of them has been answered in satisfactory way.

Thank you in advance for your help.

UPDATE: I'm starting to think that either I am missing something or nobody is using AuthSub in ASP.NET...

Answer (score 1):

I've recently created a sample how to use Google OAuth in ASP.NET and Google using the Dotnet OpenAuth library:

[Using Google OAuth in asp.net](http://www.dominikamon.com/articles/2918/using-google-oauth-in-aspnet.html)

I hope this sample helps :)
Dominik

**UPDATE March, 2015**

By April 20th, Google will no longer support this api - Therefore I needed to migrate to OIDC. See my recent article here:
[OIDC lightweight library for asp.net](http://www.dominikamon.com/articles/3091/oidc-lightweight-library-for-aspnet.html)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use OAuth, you must register your domain with Google at the following page: https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageDomains.  This registration will give you the credentials you need to sign your OAuth requests.  However, you could still specify a different oauth_callback url in the user authorization url.  So the registered domain is not related to the oauth_callback.